Dependency issue in virtual environment
I tried installing spacy but got the following error message:
blis 1.0.1 has requirement numpy<3.0.0,>=2.0.0, but you have numpy 1.23.5.
thinc 8.3.2 has requirement numpy<2.1.0,>=2.0.0; python_version >= "3.9", but you have numpy 1.23.5.

I have many other packages in the environment, when I try upgrading numpy to resolve the issue, I get the following error message:
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
contourpy 1.2.0 requires numpy<2.0,>=1.20, but you have numpy 2.0.2 which is incompatible.
matplotlib 3.7.3 requires numpy<2,>=1.20, but you have numpy 2.0.2 which is incompatible.
pandas 2.2.0 requires numpy<2,>=1.23.2; python_version == "3.11", but you have numpy 2.0.2 which is incompatible.
pyarrow 15.0.0 requires numpy<2,>=1.16.6, but you have numpy 2.0.2 which is incompatible.
pywavelets 1.5.0 requires numpy<2.0,>=1.22.4, but you have numpy 2.0.2 which is incompatible.
scikit-learn 1.4.1.post1 requires numpy<2.0,>=1.19.5, but you have numpy 2.0.2 which is incompatible.
scipy 1.12.0 requires numpy<1.29.0,>=1.22.4, but you have numpy 2.0.2 which is incompatible.
statsmodels 0.14.1 requires numpy<2,>=1.18, but you have numpy 2.0.2 which is incompatible.


What python version do you use? do you work in a separate environment?

I have python 3.9.8 and yes i am working on a separate environment that I solely made for data science related tasks.

For each new data science project/subject I make a new environment to limit dependency issues and because if next month I have to change a library version my previous project still work. Not sure that it will solve your problem but I would start with a fresh environment and install only the libraries I need for the current project.

Thanks this worked, I guess the issue was because I had a lot of packages in a single environment :)
